# NotSerializableException when invoking a ejb method with io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl as parameter

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, wildfly-10

I'm trying to migrate from JBoss 4.2 to Widfly 10. When accessing an ejb method with io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl as parameter I'm getting NotSerializableException. Below is the trace.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:253)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:128)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:328)
... 64 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you call remote EJB and class io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl is not serializable. All objects passed to remote EJB calls must be serializable.

Comment: thanks for confirming this.I thought there might be a way to get around this. I changed all methods passing the http request object and it seems to work now.